# Obter a quantidade de algarismos pares de um numero informado pelo usuário através de recursão

Tags: c, c++, recursão

Preciso obter a quantidade de algarismos pares de um número informado pelo usuário utilizando recursão.

Exemplo: 1452

Saída: "O numero informado possui 2 algarismos pares"

A única coisa que consegui fazer foi obter a quantidade de algarismos do número, mas não estou conseguindo verificar quais são pares.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numDigitosPares(int n)
{
    int cont = 1;
    if (n >= 10)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        cont += numDigitosPares(n);
    }
    return cont;
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        int qtd = numDigitosPares(n);
        printf("Quantidade de digitos: %d", qtd);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("informe um numero maior que 0 !!!!!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua função `numDigitosPares`, **verifique se a divisão daquele algarismo por dois tem resto**. Isso pode ser feito com o operador módulo (`%`):

```
//...

if (n % 2 == 0) {

}

//...
```

Um exemplo de implementação do operador seria algo como:

```
// Veja que nesta implementação a função recebe o estado do contador
// e o transmite para as demais chamadas com um valor padrão na primeira chamada (int count = 0).
// A chamada dessa função continua da mesma forma: int qtd = numDigitosPares(n);
int numDigitosPares(int n, int count = 0)
{
    if (n >= 1)
    {
        int digit = n % 10;
        
        if (digit % 2 == 0)
        {
            count += 1;
        }
        
        return numDigitosPares(n / 10, count);
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

E a verificação ou a "mensagem de erro" na primeira chamada está incorreta:

```
if (n >= 0)
{
    int qtd = numDigitosPares(n);
    printf("Quantidade de digitos: %d", qtd);
}
else
{
    printf("informe um numero maior que 0 !!!!!!");
}
```

Para isso, coloque a condição como:

```
if (n > 0) {
```

Ou mude a mensagem de erro para:

```
printf("informe um numero maior ou igual a 0 !!!!!!");
```

Da forma que deixou, o usuário poderia passar 0 para a sua função dado a verificação de `n >= 0`.

Comment: Cara, deu certo ! Muito obrigado !
Em relação a validação no método main, o objetivo é de não aceitar números menores que 0. A validação estava correta, mas na correria e estresse de não conseguir verificar quais algarismos são pares acabei esquecendo de corrigir a mensagem.
Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda !